# Custom widgets with Symfony2/Twig

Tags: symfony, widget, twig

Is it possible with Symfony2 to create our own widgets for Twig ?
I would like to do something like this :

```
{{ form_address(form.address) }}
```

Which uses something like that :

```
{{ form_row(address.street) }}
{{ form_row(address.city) }}
{{ form_row(address.postal_code) }}
{{ form_row(address.country) }}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create new form types, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is it. I'm quite new with Symfony...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is simple to do, you shouldn't be doing it. Form theming is the way to go and if you have entities that share address, than use http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html

If that address form type returns

```
public function getName() { return "address"; }
```

put

```
{{ block address_widget }} 
{{ form_row(form.street) }}
{{ form_row(form.city) }}
{{ form_row(form.postal_code) }}
{{ form_row(form.country) }}
...
```

and it will work.

Comment: looks like a nasty workaround, I want to write {{ form_row(form.address) }} and no other way

Answer (score 0):

This functionality exists and is called [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). It works a bit different than you describe above, but I think it will suit your needs.

Comment: I read the documentation about theming, but it seems I can only override the theme of an existing widget. What I want is to create a completely new widget, based on other widgets. I don't want to modify the other widgets.